# import vue.js plugin is undefined

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6, vue.js, babeljs

I have one project is a vue.js plugin, another is a vue.js SPA.

But I try to import my vue.js plugin in SPA project always undefined.

vue.js plugin export like this:

```
export function install(Vue,config){
  //do something
}
```

and it's webpack output is set to `umd`

And I import my plugin like this:

```
import MyPlugin from 'my-plugin'
console.log(MyPlugin)//undefined
Vue.use(MyPlugin)//throw error 'Cannot read property 'install' of undefined'
```

So I inspect code in compiled `bundle.js` then I saw this

```
console.log(_myplugin2.default);
```

But how can I make it force to use `_myplugin2` as plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Webpack is assuming that you have exported a `default` property.

You can do that like so:

```
export default {
  install: function(Vue,config) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

---

If you don't want to use `default`, you'll need to export it using a named variable:

```
export const MyPlugin = {
  install: function(Vue,config) {
    //do something
  }
}
```

And then specifically reference that variable reference that when importing:

```
import { MyPlugin } from 'my-plugin'
```

[Here's a working example.](https://www.webpackbin.com/bins/-KvXImUQZy4AYVUU9zYM)

Comment: I tried this but when I include the script in html script tag I need to use extra `default`

Comment: I want to make module can be import from node_modules and included by script tag

Comment: Not sure what you mean, I've added a working example to my answer

Comment: [webpack config](https://github.com/maple3142/vuejs-storage/blob/master/webpack.config.js), I mean when I use you code then include the `build.js`(module) in browser will output module to `window.myplugin.default` instead of `window.myplugin`

Comment: I added an example not using `default`. But, why do you need to access your plugin after you've built the application?

Comment: But take `Vuex` for example, I can `import Vuex from 'Vuex'` or use it in browser `Vue.use(window.Vuex)`, I wish my plugin can work like that

Comment: I am trying to create a plugin using webpack for practice only

Comment: How are these things being set to the `window`? Is that happening through the build process?

Comment: webpack libraryTarget:`umd` [this](https://github.com/maple3142/vuejs-storage/blob/master/dist/vuejs-storage.js)

Answer (score 1):

I finally use another script as webpack entry.

entry.js:

```
module.exports=require('./main')
```

main.js:

```
function install(Vue,config){
  //something
}
export default {install}
```

then it can be access in `window.myplugin` and `import myplugin from 'myplugin'`